# Advent of Code 2019 Day 1: What's wrong with my math/logic?

Tags: python, math

The following is the prompt for Advent of Code 2019 Day 1 Part 1:

> Santa has become stranded at the edge of the Solar System while delivering presents to other planets! To accurately calculate his position in space, safely align his warp drive, and return to Earth in time to save Christmas, he needs you to bring him measurements from fifty stars.
>
> Collect stars by solving puzzles. Two puzzles will be made available on each day in the Advent calendar; the second puzzle is unlocked when you complete the first. Each puzzle grants one star. Good luck!
>
> The Elves quickly load you into a spacecraft and prepare to launch.
>
> At the first Go / No Go poll, every Elf is Go until the Fuel Counter-Upper. They haven't determined the amount of fuel required yet.
>
> Fuel required to launch a given module is based on its mass. Specifically, to find the fuel required for a module, take its mass, divide by three, round down, and subtract 2.
>
> For example:
>
> For a mass of 12, divide by 3 and round down to get 4, then subtract 2 to get 2.
> For a mass of 14, dividing by 3 and rounding down still yields 4, so the fuel required is also 2.
> For a mass of 1969, the fuel required is 654.
> For a mass of 100756, the fuel required is 33583.
> The Fuel Counter-Upper needs to know the total fuel requirement. To find it, individually calculate the fuel needed for the mass of each module (your puzzle input), then add together all the fuel values.
>
> What is the sum of the fuel requirements for all of the modules on your spacecraft?

Here are two versions of my attempt:

```
'''
Simplification:

total fuel = (m1 / 3 - 2) + (m2 / 3 - 2) + (m3 / 3 - 2) + ... + (mn / 3 - 2)

total fuel = (m1 / 3) + (m2 / 3) + ... + (mn / 3) - 2 - 2 - ... - 2

total fuel = (1 / 3)(m1 + ... + mn) - 2 * n
'''

# Why doesn't this work?
print(sum(masses) // 3 - 2 * len(masses))

# This works, though...
print(sum([m // 3 - 2 for m in masses]))
```

The first print yields `3384266`, while the second yields `3384232`, the correct answer.

So... What exactly is wrong with the first version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the difference is the rounding, your simplification doesn't account for that.

Consider the following (two units at weight `2` (yes they'd go negative but ignore the `- 2` for a second)):

```
>>> (2 // 3 + 2 // 3)
0
>>> (2 + 2) // 3
1
```

Comment: But shouldn't the real answer be 1 to that? Rounding each individual `2` results in more loss of information than if you were to sum up all the masses and then round down with division. Because without integer division, `2 / 3 + 2 / 3 = 4 / 3`, and _that_ rounded down is `1`.

Comment: nope! the problem tells you to consider each module separately

Answer (score 0):

Both those answers seem wrong.

You need to sum each element, thus

```
// psuedocode
total = 0

loop -> element
    total += floor(element / 3) - 2
```

That should give you the correct answer.

edit:

As another person said, your issue might be rounding. You need to floor the value / 3

Comment: The second implementation `sum([m // 3 - 2 for m in masses])` is correct.

Comment: @KieranMoynihan I guess it might be, but the answer he posted isn't the correct answer to the advent of code question.

Comment: The input is user dependent.